# What's a good starter book of Cartier-Bresson photographs?

Tags: books, photographer, inspiration, cartier-bresson

I want to learn about Henri Cartier-Bresson's work.  Can someone recommend a book of his work to get me started?

I specifically want to be able to look at a lot of his images, rather than reading a biography or critique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Henri Cartier-Bresson: The Man, The Image & The World" is a great book. Large prints, good quality and a comprehensive selection.

Another book to consider is "Henri Cartier-Bresson: The Modern Century" which was printed to accompany the MoMA exhibit by the same name.